# Append not mongodb syslog to /var/log/mongodb/mongodb.log

Tags: linux, mongodb

i setting one crontab linux for remove some data on my mongo database, in crontab i use : [my action] >> /var/log/mongodb/mongodb.log 2>&1. 
when i view log live by "tail -f /var/log/mongodb/mongodb.log" i can see my custom log, So i setting linux cron run at 23:00. The next day, i get mongodb.log and read it, but my log is gone. I don't know why. My cron's action exactly was done, but hadn't any log record. Please help me.

My cron's action log format: "[ERROR] ... My message "

Comment: Is the file probably rotated?

Comment: No it rotate at 00:00 daily, but my cron was ran at 23:00. I find all log at 23:00 ~ .... but nothing. Just only syslog mongodb